# Count number of events per user

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

i have table similar to this:

```
ID | event | user | time | note | archived
```

I need the number of events that individual users have been to, but one user can have more than one record for one event, so I only need to count it once.

**The result should look like this:**

```
user | nrofevents
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can you show use what you tried? We need to see your efforts. Advice: You can use **COUNT()** and **GROUP BY()** to achieve your desired results.

Comment: "**Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.** Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you." --> [Quoted from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Hi, i have tried this query: SELECT user, count(user) as nrofevents FROM `harmo` WHERE GROUP BY event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly it's just the use of *distinct* you need?

```
select user, count(distinct event) as nrofevents
from t
group by user;
```